# Suggest test automation tool for filling dynamically created forms using jquery and Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, automated-tests

In which testing tool we can write test scripts to automate form filling in dynamically created forms using jquery and html?

I am web developer and I use Selenium for automation of forms I am not sure  if Selenium supports for writing test scripts for dynamically created forms using Jquery. Can anyone tell me whether selenium supports this feature. If not please suggest any other tools or testing technologies that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium scripts can only be used where the structure of forms is already known like you should have the knowledge of what html elements are being used, what is the name or id or class used for the html element. 
Automated form filling can be done only if we know these elements in advance. The order in which these elements appear may not be a problem. But if the forms are generated dynamically where new html elements are created, selenium scripts will not work.

Comment: Thank you, do you know any other solutions for automating filling of dynamically created forms using Jquery.